# How do I install Flysystem and Flysystem S3?

Tags: files, 8

I'm using the [Flysystem](https://www.drupal.org/project/flysystem) module, but I am not able to install the module. I am getting this error:

> Dependencies missing: Flysystem, replicate adapter, stream wrapper.

I followed the steps given on https://www.drupal.org/node/2541116, but I am still not able to install the module.

I have installed the [Replicate](https://www.drupal.org/project/replicate) and [Stream wrapper](https://www.drupal.org/project/system_stream_wrapper) modules.

Is there any other method to integrate S3 with Drupal 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That documentation you referenced is outdated and wrong. You should read the official documentation on https://www.drupal.org/node/2404989.

The easiest way to do this is to install the drupal modules with composer, as documented on https://www.drupal.org/node/2718229. Once you've configured the drupal.org repository, installing a module is as simple as `composer require drupal/flysystem`. That will download that module, including alll dependencies that it needs for you.

You can manage your whole installation, including core, with composer if you use `composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev`. You can also add contrib modules if you installed drupal core by hand, but when updating core, you need to be careful to not lose your composer.json changes and run composer update again.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, ill try above procedure and check it out.

Answer (score 1):

There is a module called [S3 File System](https://www.drupal.org/project/s3fs)

> S3 File System (s3fs) provides an additional file system to your
>   drupal site, which stores files in Amazon's Simple Storage Service
>   (S3) or any other S3-compatible storage service. You can set your site
>   to use S3 File System as the default, or use it only for individual
>   fields. This functionality is designed for sites which are
>   load-balanced across multiple servers, as the mechanism used by
>   Drupal's default file systems is not viable under such a configuration

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Could you please share your opinion to both modules and compare them?